# Pass object in spring form input hidden SpringMVC

Tags: spring, jsp

i have problem with pass object(CarType) in spring input form.

My Car model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CAR")
public class Car implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CAR_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "REG_NO", nullable=false)
    private String regNo;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "YEAR", nullable=false, length = 4)
    private String year;

    @Column(name = "AVAILABLE", nullable=false)
    private boolean available = true;

    @Column(name = "START_DATE")
    private String startDate;

    @Column(name = "RETURN_DATE")
    private String returnDate;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CAR_TYPE_ID")
    private CarType carType;

//getters and setters
```

Car Type model:

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "CAR_TYPE")
    public class CarType {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "CAR_TYPE_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
        private int id;

        @NotEmpty
        @Column(name = "MARK", nullable=false)
        private String mark;

        @NotEmpty
        @Column(name = "MODEL", nullable=false)
        private String model;

//getters and setters
```

Controllers:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/rent-car-{regNo}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String rentCar(@PathVariable String regNo, ModelMap model) {
        Car car = carService.findCarByRegNo(regNo);
        model.addAttribute("car", car);
        return "rentcar";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/rent-car-{regNo}" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveRentCar(@Valid Car car,  BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
        carService.updateCar(car);
        model.addAttribute("success", "Car " + car.getRegNo() + " rented successfully");
        return "registrationsuccess";
    }
```

JSP file

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="car" class="form-horizontal">
                <form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id"/>
                <form:input type="hidden" path="year" id="year"/>
                <form:input type="hidden" path="regNo" id="regNo"/>
                <form:input type="hidden" path="available" id="available"/>
                <form:input type="hidden" path="carType" id="carType"/>
 <form:input type="text" path="startDate" id="startDate"/>
<form:input type="text" path="returnDate" id="returnDate"/>
```

I have problem with that code

```
<form:input type="hidden" path="carType" id="carType"/>
```

how can i pass object CarType to Car form? I always have that same error: column 'CAR_TYPE_ID' cannot be null. It looks like I'm transferring a null CarType to Car. I dont know why?
Someone can help me? In registercar.jsp i used converter (convert regNo to class CarType) and its works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know how the `Car` object gets bound in the Controller handler method from http request from the client. Spring MVC maps the the request parameters to contruct the `Car` object. Hence the `CarType` is an associated object. You need to provide a minimal clue to Spring MVC to construct that for you.

```
  <form:form method="POST" action="/rent-car${regNo}" modelAttribute="car">
       ......
       <form:input type="hidden" path="carType.id"/>
       <form:input type="hidden" path="carType.model"/>
       <form:input type="hidden" path="carType.mark"/>

       <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </form:form>
```

you will find a complementary example here is this article [Spring MVC - Binding Request Parameters and Path Variables to Java Backing Objects](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/spring-request-param-data-binding.html)

Comment: I have that same error, Its look like CarType is not created despite i pass id,mark and model. When i print ${car.carType.id} on JSP i have good id carType.

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'CAR_TYPE_ID' cannot be null

Comment: `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:` is related to your persistent layer issue. Its not about the Spring mvc data binding

Comment: this is occurring inside  your `carService.updateCar(car);` method. you are trying to persist `Car` and cascading relationship with `CarType` without giving any hints about it to JPA

Comment: https://imgur.com/q5YdGxU
CarType is still NULL, I think problem is with that form, but dont know why springmvc doesnt create this object.

Comment: In debuger have that error:
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.OneToOne @javax.persistence.JoinColumn com.rentcar.app.model.CarType] for value 'BMW X5'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "BMW X5"]

Where BMW X5 is CarType.toString

Comment: I override method CarType.toString to return String.valueOf(id); 
now converter works. Thanks for help.

Comment: Spring MVC by default uses `toString` method to bind data. But you may not want to override `toString` for this. I tested your code locally in my side. and finds no problem with binding. Please re check your code and address what you are doing wrong. Always try to follow best practice

Comment: I tried this way and it works like a charm!. thanks very much. :)